# Access control for content generated with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, access-control, rbac

Anybody knows if Sphinx supports access management/control?
Until now, I have been using Sphinx to generate documentation for a single general target audience.

Currently, I would like to serve various content automatically to three different groups:

1. Basic users
2. Intermediate users
3. Advanced users

The ideas is to have my content in a repository and serve different contents based on the target audience. Following this approach, Basic users would see a different content than advanced users.
Did anybody try to implement such a concept before, or do you know if Sphinx supports such a functionality?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Do you mean something like [tag:rbac]? Sphinx itself does not have any support for that. Does it matter if a "basic" user can access "advanced" content?

Comment: @mzjn: Thank you! Exactly, what I would like to implement is a role based access to resources. Depending on the scenario, a basic user would not be allowed to access  advanced content. For example, basic user does not have administrator rights to perform certain tasks and is therefore not allowed to see how some processes work.
Can I integrate rbac in a Sphinx toolchain?

Comment: As Sphinx generates raw files for hosting, you can plug them into a web server that supports authentication and URL based authorization such as Windows/IIS. If you want to use another web server, check its documentation for similar configuration.

Comment: @LexLi: Thank you very much for the hint. Very much appreciated!